# Python command removed from PATH when adding PIP

Tags: python, cmd, path, pip

I started by downloading Python and adding it to the PATH variable

```
setx PATH c:\Python27
```

Next when I run the Python command it works

Next I installed pip and I had to add it to de PATH variable

```
setx PATH c:\Python27\scripts
```

Now when I run the PIP command it works, but when I try to run the Python command it does not work anymore.

So I reset de Python command to the PATH variable, but it removes the PIP command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as far as i know setx will set the value and not append to it
so inorder to do what you want you should do

```
setx PATH %PATH%;<NEWADDITION>
```